# Unable to click on button available on the page

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

```
<button class="md-trigger btn btn-primary mrg-b-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="CaseProcessmodal" id="AddCaseButton" onclick="return validateForm('#CaseProcessmodal');">Add Case</button>
```

I have an element location like above, trying to click on the button in selenium, its not working. I am using page factory, element id is correctly matching though.

Verified with other matching element id.

Comment: Please format your question and add information like the page source, the code that you've used and what error you're facing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution to this putting if condition, agian applied click action. it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The desired element is within a *Modal Dialog* so to `click()` on the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("button.md-trigger.btn.btn-primary.mrg-b-lg#AddCaseButton[data-target='CaseProcessmodal']"))).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@class='md-trigger btn btn-primary mrg-b-lg' and @id='AddCaseButton'][text()='Add Case']"))).click();
  ```

Comment: I have already tried with wait formulae: Utils.scrollIntoView(driver, AddcaseButton);
  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.refreshed(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(AddcaseButton))); its not workign either. Tried giving wait, action etc everything. After click on teh button there would be a processing screen and should close the window. click action is not working atall